# Vulkan on devices that share host memory

Tags: vulkan

For the purpose of this question, we'll say `vkMapMemory` for all allocations on such a device cannot fail; they are trivially host-visible, and the result is a direct pointer to some other region of host memory (no work needs to be done).

Is there some way to detect this situation?

The purpose in mind is an arena-based allocator that aggressively maps any host-visible memory, and an objective is to avoid redundant allocations on such hardware.

Comment: "*no work needs to be done*" Could you explain what "work" would "need to be done" on some other kind of device? It's not clear what this kind of situation avoids.

Comment: It's a bit pedantic, but vkMapMemory can still fail for host allocations, due to CPU virtual address space fragmentation for example.

Comment: The "device" I had in mind might have been better described as a software rasterizer. Though, implementations for UMA-based systems described by @krOoze have little reason to _not_ expose direct pointers to buffer data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be detected relatively reliably.

If `vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties` has only one Memory Heap (which would be labeled `VK_MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT`) then it is certain it is the same memory as host.

In words of the authors:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#memory-device

> In a unified memory architecture (UMA) system, there is often only a single memory heap which is considered to be equally “local” to the host and to the device, and such an implementation must advertise the heap as device-local.

In other cases you know trivially if the memory is on the host (i.e. the given Memory Heap on dGPU would **not** have `VK_MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` set)

Comment: If I understand correctly then the condition for UMA is `(props.memoryHeapCount == 1) && (props.memoryTypeCount == 1) && (props.memoryTypes[0].propertyFlags & VK_MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT)`. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: @plasmacel That may be brittle, someone could add a memory type (e.g. for `PROTECTED`). I quote the spec language. Its transliteration to code would be `props.memoryHeapCount == 1 && (props.memoryHeaps[0].flags & VK_MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT)` (BTW, the flags check is redundant; if there is only one heap, it is spec guarantee that it is `DEVICE_LOCAL`).

Comment: @plasmacel Although there might be some nonsense, and practically this is not true. There might be multiple heaps, such as [here](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=9471#memoryheaps). What likely be true is there wouldn't be any host-local heap, although I could theoretically imagine otherwise too.

Comment: What about iterating each memory heap and checking for the `VK_MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` flag bit. If every heap have this flag bit, that should imply that all of them is device local, i.e.its UMA. Am I missing something?

Comment: @plasmacel That's probably what I would do. UMA GPU has little reason to expose a `HOST_LOCAL` heap (`VkMemory` object always represents a memory the GPU can directly use, so in the case of UMA there `DEVICE_LOCAL` and `HOST_LOCAL` heap would be functionally an identical thing). Though as I said, I could imagine otherwise and weasel up a way in which case `HOST_LOCAL` heap would make sense on a UMA. One caveat to this aproach still is that an extension could add some unknown flag to Memory Heaps; some heap could lack the `DEVICE_LOCAL` and instead have some unknown flag bit set.

Comment: In retrospect, my AMD Ryzen 7 APU exposes a non-`DEVICE_LOCAL` heap, which maps to `HOST_VISIBLE` memory types, so I think the above logic is insufficient to detect an unified memory architecture system. I think it is better to rely on `VkPhysicalDeviceProperties::deviceType == VK_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_INTEGRATED_GPU`.

Comment: @plasmacel It seems Vega has its own dedicated\reserved memory it does not allow CPU to touch, so it still checks out?

Answer (score 2):

> Though, implementations for UMA-based systems described by @krOoze have little reason to not expose direct pointers to buffer data.

Your question seems to proceed from a false assumption.

Vulkan is *not* OpenGL. Generally speaking, it does not try to hide things from you. If a memory heap cannot be accessed directly by the CPU, then the Vulkan implementation will not expose a memory type for that heap that is host-visible. Conversely, if a memory heap *can* be accessed directly by the CPU, then the Vulkan implementation will expose a memory type for that heap that is host-visible.

Therefore, if you can map a device allocation *at all* in Vulkan, then you should assume that you have a "direct pointer to buffer data".